# "Я свободен как/словно птица". Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как

*Я свободен как/словно птица.*
Вроде бы не фразеологизм. Если убрать как/словно птица предложение не утратит смысловой нагрузки.

Comment: Почему при использовании словно требуется особый анализ предложения в данном случае? Разве в этом предложении словно и как могут выполнять разные функции?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Я свободен как птИца.**  (При использовании союза ***словно*** нужно анализировать предложение).

**Надо ли решать вопрос: это фразеологизм или нет?**

Фразеологизм — устойчивое выражение со значением одного слова, обычно наречия. Занимая в предложении позицию наречия, фразеологизмы не обособляются. Это обычно касается **общеизвестных фразеологизмов,** не имеющих никаких изменений (белый как снег).

**В других случаях надо определять синтаксическую роль оборота.** Сравнительный оборот не обособляется в роли обстоятельства в основном сообщении, при этом л**огическое ударение с глагола/прилагательного  переносится на оборот**, а пауза отсутствует.

**В реальности это возможно в коротких предложениях,** но достаточно хотя бы немного дополнить и усложнить структуру предложения или оборота, и он уже  обособляется, так как перестает вписываться в предложение (это же всё-таки оборот, а не наречие).

Примеры из современной литературы:

Я проводил в Грузии отпуск и был **свободен как птИца**.

Грубо говоря, это всё запихивается в два чемодана, и я **свободен как птИца.**

Ему представляется, что он «идет по полю быстро, весело, постукивая палочкой, а над ним широкое небо, залитое солнцем, и он теперь **свобОден, как птИца,** может идти куда угодно!

Зато в сцене «суда», которую я мало репетировал, я в сумасшедшем монологе Ивана Карамазова отводил свою душу и был **свобОден, как птИца в полете…**

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю, "свободен как птица" — устойчивое выражение, поэтому запятая не нужна.
В подтверждение могу сослаться на [ответ Грамоты](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=236834): "В сентябре я выпускаю 6-ю книгу – и свободен как птица."

Справедливости ради должен сказать, что в Нацкорпусе встречаются оба варианта:

Их арестуют, и ты станешь **свободным как птица**. [Токарева Виктория. Своя правда // «Новый Мир», 2002]

― Вот когда ты **свободен, как птица**, ― остановившись, ласково говорит мне Трофимов. [А. С. Новиков-Прибой. По-темному (1912)]